# Who do you think I (Met / met with)?

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

> Who do you think I **met/met with** ?

Considering *formal* usage of English do we need to use preposition *with* with *met* in the above given sentence ? I tried to google about it but couldn't find anything reliable.

Comment: Both are fine.  You can consider "met" and "met with" as two separate verbs with similar meaning.

Comment: @Andrew I disagree. I was taught that **met with** is to share a meeting and **met** means stumbled up.

Comment: @SovereignSun  Yes, two separate, grammatical verbs with *similar* meaning.  Which you use depends on what you want to say, but both are equally "correct" given the context.

Answer (score 4):

Since you mention "formal" you might prefer "With whom do you think I met?"

There is a small difference in meaning between "meet", and "meet with". The former suggests a short chance event. "I met John at the shops". The latter suggests a planned meeting. "I met with John to discuss our plans" This distinction is flexible and not always observed.

Hence use "Who do you think I met with" to ask "Who do you think I had a planned meeting with". And "Who do you think I met?" to ask "who do you think I bumped into"

In either case, asking such a question is very conversational, rather than formal.